# Counting the number of comparisons and moves made during sorting

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I am doing insertion sort and was wondering if the number of comparisons made and number of moves made were calculated properly. Comparisons are the number of times two values were compared and moves are the number of elements moved, so a swap between numbers will be 2 moves.

```
public static int[] InsertionSort(int[] a) {
    int j;
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        int tmp = a[i];
        for(j = i; j > 0 && (tmp < a[j-1]); j--) {
            numCompares++;
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            numMoves++;
        }
        a[j] = tmp; 
        numMoves++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Very good, Do you have a question?

Comment: Are the numCompares++ and numMoves++ placed in the right place to get the right count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem here is that in inner loop condition `j > 0 && (tmp < a[j-1])`, actual comparison `tmp < a[j-1]` may result false, causing break of `for` loop, so `numCompares++` which is located inside the loop will be skipped. To count comparisons precisely, small reformat is required:

```
for(j = i; j > 0; j--) {
    numCompares++; 
    if (tmp >= a[j - 1])
        break; 
    a[j] = a[j - 1];
    numMoves++;
}
```

Comment: Or you could use a hack `j > 0 && numCompares++ >= 0 && tmp < a[j-1]`

Comment: @PeterLawrey well, this is even better :)